# Linear layout imageviews on either sides

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout which has two images views. I want each of them to be on opposite ends.One of left end and other on right end.I tried using gravity but didn't work. Here's my code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.972"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shopicon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you provide an screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, if this is what you mean

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.972"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shopicon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you got exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

First of all, here the image width is very small. So you can use `FrameLayout` then add `android:layout_gravity="start"` for the first image-view and `android:layout_gravity="end"` for second one. And you don't need to add constraints for children of other than `ConstraintLayout`. See bellow layout.

```
  <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/shopicon"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```